# TraceBack (most recent call last), and GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) or GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) errors

Tags: python, microcontroller, gpio

I have been struggling with a script that will turn a Pi's BCM pins 17, 27, and 10 on for 1 second then off for 1 second sequentially 100ish times. When I run the script LED1 will turn on and then it turns off and the program shuts down with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LedBlink.py", line 47, in <module>
    LED2Blink()
  File "LedBlink.py", line 27, in LED2Blink
    GPIO.setup(LED2, GPIO.OUT)
RuntimeError: Please set pin numbering mode using     GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) or GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

LED1 = 17
LED2 = 27
LED3 = 10

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

def LED1Blink():
        GPIO.setup(LED1, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(LED1,True) 
        time.sleep(1)  
        GPIO.output(LED1,False)
        time.sleep(1)
        GPIO.cleanup()

def LED2Blink():
        GPIO.setup(LED2, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(LED2,True) 
        time.sleep(1)  
        GPIO.output(LED2,False)
        time.sleep(1)
        GPIO.cleanup()

def LED3Blink():
        GPIO.setup(LED3, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(LED3,True) 
        time.sleep(1)  
        GPIO.output(LED3,False)
        time.sleep(1)
        GPIO.cleanup()

i = 0
while i < 100:
       LED1Blink()
       LED2Blink()
       LED3Blink()
       i + 1
else:
       print "finished loop"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `GPIO.cleanup()` at the end of each methods. As stated in the [documentation](http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/BasicUsage/), `Note that GPIO.cleanup() also clears the pin numbering system in use.` What you want is `GPIO.cleanup(channel)` instead, where channel corresponds to `LED1, LED2, LED3` in your script.

The best practice is to **setup** and **cleanup** the channels **ONLY ONCE**, e.g.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

LED1 = 17
LED2 = 27
LED3 = 10

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(LED1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(LED2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(LED3, GPIO.OUT)

def LED1Blink():
        GPIO.output(LED1,True) 
        time.sleep(1)  
        GPIO.output(LED1,False)
        time.sleep(1)

def LED2Blink():
        GPIO.output(LED2,True) 
        time.sleep(1)  
        GPIO.output(LED2,False)
        time.sleep(1)

def LED3Blink():
        GPIO.output(LED3,True) 
        time.sleep(1)  
        GPIO.output(LED3,False)
        time.sleep(1)

i = 0
if i < 100:
       LED1Blink()
       LED2Blink()
       LED3Blink()
       i + 1
else:
       GPIO.cleanup()
       print "finished loop"
```

Answer (score 2):

Never call GPIO.cleanup() more than once as alongwith clearing the PINS, it also clears the Pin MODE! So, if you have called it in between a program, then next statement execution wouldn't have a pin MODE and that'll give out an Error.
"TraceBack (most recent call last), and GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) or GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) errors"

So, Always use it at end or wherever the program could end/break in between if certain condition is met.